# Regex pluck parts too, not whole string

Tags: php, regex

This is my input content:

```
$input = 'Hi there,

You recently ... {{client.events.add_to_cart.product_name}}, ...

..

Also

...

{{client.events.purchase.product_name}}
';
```

and this is regex example:

```
$regex = "'(?:\{\{client\.events\.)\w+(?:\.)\w+(?:\}\})'";

preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches);
```

This is the `$matches` content:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "{{client.events.add_to_cart.product_name}}"
    1 => "{{client.events.purchase.product_name}}"
  ]
]
```

Not bad, but I'd like somehow to pick "add_to_cart" and "product_name" as well. I can do it with `explode()` function, but wonder if there is a way to do this by regex only once.

Also, I wonder if it is possible to have 'target' these too:

- `{{client.events.add_to_cart.product_name}}`
- `{{client.events.add_to_cart.0.product_name}}`
- `{{client.events.add_to_cart.1.product_name}}`

with and without numbers. And also knowing the number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it: `(\{\{client\.events\.(?:purchase|(add_to_cart))(?:\.\d)?\.(.*)\}\})`

See: https://regex101.com/r/EKAJsG/1

Comment: Thank you. I modified it a bit so it looks: ```(\{\{client\.events\.(.*)(?:\.\d)?\.(.*)\}\})``` because I want to support multiple events and event attributes.

Comment: Well, you explicitly asked for `add_to_cart`, and actually, it was the hardest part to only match for that, but not other events. ;-) Anyhow, I learned something, so that's ok.

Comment: Yes I did. My mistake. :) Thanks again.